# Report performance optimization

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, navision, microsoft-dynamics-nav, dynamics-nav-2016, dynamics-nav-2015

How can I get only once signature picture from UserSetup in DataSet?

DataItem Integer in the end doesn't work when I print two or more documents with different signatures.

Comment: More details please.

Answer (score 0):

The usual tactics is to clear BLOB with a picture after the first row has been generated, e.g. in AfterGetRecord of document lines.

An example with more details can be found here:

http://www.softwareanswers.co.uk/software_answers/2015/01/outofmemoryexception-when-running-dynamics-nav-reports.html